# What characters are allowed in MariaDB Full Text Search IN BOOLEAN MODE?

Tags: php, full-text-search, mariadb

I want to pass user input through PHP to an SQL query on a MariaDB 10.1.37 InnoDB table to do a search. I want to protect against building invalid SQL queries. Currently I am removing the known operator characters like this:

```
preg_replace('/[\+\-\<\>\(\)\~\*\"]/', ' ', $user_input)
```

Then I append a `*` character to each word. So if the user input is `foo bar` the query will be:

```
SELECT columnname, MATCH(columnname) AGAINST('foo* bar*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM tablename;
```

Unfortunately there are other characters that a user can input that will break the query. For example, if the user inputs `%` the query will be `AGAINST('%*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` which gives the error: `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'` .

I could try to filter out characters that cause problems (a blacklist) or I could try to whitelist characters that I know are ok.

I can't find anything in the documentation to define what characters are allowed or disallowed.

Is there a known set of characters that is either allowed or disallowed?

Comment: Seems like if you want to prevent them using operators in the search you should whitelist only what you want to allow or escape things properly if you want to be more permissive.

Comment: I'm removing the full list of operators. % is not an operator in the context of a IN BOOLEAN MODE search, but it is also not a valid character.

Comment: Think it is still a "pattern matching context"...  To actual full-text search that would be `\%*`. Agree it is confusing. I still find these errors in logs... And opted to typically just treat the error as 'no matches returned..." for all intent and purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Take the opposite approach?  Decide what characters to allow.

```
$x = preg_replace("/[^-'a-zA-Z0-9]/", ' ', $user_input);
$x = trim($x, '-');
```

Keep:

- Dash for hyphenated words
- Apostrophe for contractions
- Trim off things that might cause trouble

Remove:

- Plus and asterisk -- because of FT syntax
- Slash and double-quote -- PHP syntax

Then use double-quotes, not apostrophe, in

```
AGAINST("foo* bar*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(See also the Comments, below.)

Comment: This still breaks, if the user enters a dash at the *end* of a word, e.g., `MATCH(col) AGAINST('foo-*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will generate an error. I agree dashes should be allowed, but they should be removed in a trim function too after replacing everything else, like this: `trim($user_input, '- ')`.

Comment: @QuinnComendant - OK, I trimmed leading/trailing dashes.

Comment: Actually, this can all be done in one step by using multiple search criteria: `preg_replace(["/[^-'’a-z0-9]/i", "/[-'’]$/", "/^[-'’]/"], ' ', $user_input)`. It also trims apostrophes (straight and curly).